# How to add a decimal button in Javascript Calculator

Tags: html

It's a beginner project for me to learn HTML and JavaScript. Every other buttons work fine, only a dot button. Possible problem I think is that the resultado.value does not accept a decimal character and only accept numerical numbers. The resultado variable is declared in JavaScript as

```
var resultado = document.getElementById('ent')
```

This is part code in HTML that declare other numerical button and decimal button:

```
<p><input type="button" id="n1" class="keys" value="1" onclick="add1()"> <input type="button" id="n2" class="keys" value="2" onclick="add2()"> <input type="button" id="n3" class="keys" value="3" onclick="add3()"> </p>
<p><input type="button" id="n4" class="keys" value="4" onclick="add4()"> <input type="button" id="n5" class="keys" value="5" onclick="add5()"> <input type="button" id="n6" class="keys" value="6" onclick="add6()"> </p>
<p><input type="button" id="n7" class="keys" value="7" onclick="add7()"> <input type="button" id="n8" class="keys" value="8" onclick="add8()"> <input type="button" id="n9" class="keys" value="9" onclick="add9()"> </p>
```

For decimal button

```
<p><input type="button" id="pon" class="keys" value="." onclick="ponto()">
```

This is part code in JavaScript for the numerical button and decimal button:

```
function add1() { 
    resultado.value += `1`
}
function add2() {
    resultado.value += `2`
```

For decimal button but won't work

```
function ponto(){
    resultado.value += `.`
}
```

Any ideas how to add display button on display ? Thank you! Any suggestion to improve my question is appreciated also. First time asking. Thanks!

Comment: What is the HTML of the `ent` element?

Comment: There are two div, one is for user input from keyboard, one is for button
The ent element is in user input div 
<div id="entrada">
            <p>Insert numbers below</p>
            <input type="number" id="ent" class="ent" placeholder="0" step="0.01">
        </div>
This is the project link to view full code: https://github.com/AlanAlexsander/learning. Thanks

Comment: The problem is the `type="number"`. Remove it if you want to be able to append a dot to the displayed value. Of course, that will remove the extra little buttons for step increments also. But since you want to create a calculator, that `input` should not have these.

Comment: The weird things that make me keep that one is that when i input, the dot works even though the type is number. So i assume that the type is not the issue. If it is an issue, can you explain why does the dot works when i input it? I will change this part to try out also! Thanks

Comment: Well you can also add it with code, but it is the same as you enter it manually: the `value` property will not include it.